# Is it possible to get list of permissions in a file request

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm displaying the list of folders in the google drive root directory, and I want to display an icon when the folder is shared with other people, no matter who is shared with.

Is is possible to get that info in the file.list request? or I have to make a new request for each folder to get the list of permissions?

In the google docs api there was a category tag containing this info.

Regards,
Alvaro.

Answer (score -1):

When you use file.list request, the returned response body will contain the following:

```
    {
       "kind": "drive#fileList",
        "etag": etag,
        "selfLink": string,
        "nextPageToken": string,
        "nextLink": string,
        "items": [files Resource]
    }
```

Then in the [files Resource], the structure is as follows:

```
 {
   "kind": "drive#file",
   "id": string,
   "etag": etag,
   "selfLink": string,
   "webContentLink": string,
   "alternateLink": string,
   "embedLink": string,
   "thumbnailLink": string,
   "title": string,
   "mimeType": string,
   "description": string,
   "labels": {
   "starred": boolean,
   "hidden": boolean,
   "trashed": boolean,
   "restricted": boolean,
   "viewed": boolean
    },
  "createdDate": datetime,
  "modifiedDate": datetime,
  "modifiedByMeDate": datetime,
  "lastViewedByMeDate": datetime,
  "sharedWithMeDate": datetime,
  "parents": [
           parents Resource
     ],
  "downloadUrl": string,
  "exportLinks": {
  (key): string
    },
  "indexableText": {
  "text": string
    },
  "userPermission": permissions Resource,
  "originalFilename": string,
  "fileExtension": string,
  "md5Checksum": string,
  "fileSize": long,
  "quotaBytesUsed": long,
  "ownerNames": [
        string
   ],
  "lastModifyingUserName": string,
  "editable": boolean,
  "writersCanShare": boolean,
  "explicitlyTrashed": boolean,
  "imageMediaMetadata": {
      "width": integer,
      "height": integer,
      "rotation": integer,
   "location": {
       "latitude": double,
       "longitude": double,
       "altitude": double
      }
    }
 }
```

The field "userPermission" is the one you can find your answer.