# How to get the list of permissions in a file.list request?

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to get the list of permissions ID when I get a list of Files.

Currently, when I use file.list request, the [Files Resource] contains the owners permission IDs (owners[].permissionId) of each File, but I don't have the permissions IDs of the other users (WRITERS, READERS)

We have to make a request for each File to get the complete list of permissions (permissions.list), which is very heavy when there is a lot of Files.

A similar question has been asked: [Is it possible to get list of permissions in a file request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502839/is-it-possible-to-get-list-of-permissions-in-a-file-request). Unfortunately, the 'userPermission' field only returns the permissions for the authenticated user.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's just how it is. The meta data for a file is fragmented over a number of different feeds and you need to query each one. You can save a bit of http traffic by batching your request, but that's about as good as you're gonna get.